# GTK default File->Quit behavior

Tags: c, gtk, gtkmm

I've written an event event handler for my window's File->Quit button:

```
void on_file_quit() {
  int err = pthread_cancel( work ); 
  if (err) {
     std::cerr << "no thread to cancel\n";
  }
  else { 
    pthread_join( work, NULL );
  }
}
```

instantiating it this way:

```
pfile_quit->signal_activate().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(on_file_quit) );
```

I would like to make then close the window at the end of on_file_quit(), as in pressing the close button at the top of the window. I haven't found the solution anywhere. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: According to [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtkevents/), pressing the X button at the top of the window sends `destroy` signal. Send that signal or just call it's handler directly.

Comment: I've read this post... I'm new to GTK. I don't know how to *cause* this signal.

Comment: Ok, after looking around for a way to send a widget the destroy signal, I came up short. My solution was to call the window's destructor ... this seems to work cleanly. I'll post the change when stackoverflow allows me too.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the window with Gtk::Widget::hide(). If you want to do the same thing that would happen when the X button is clicked (which sends the delete_event signal), just call your on_delete_event() handler directly.

By the way, you are not "instantiating" a signal handler. You are connecting a signal handler. Also, this is gtkmm, not GTK+.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. Would calling `Gtk::Widget::hide()` close the window so that I can exit the application? My solution was simply to call the window's destructor, like so:

```
void on_file_quit() {
  int err = pthread_cancel( work ); 
  if (err) {
     std::cerr << "no thread to cancel\n";
  }
  else { 
    pthread_join( work, NULL );
  }
  delete pwindow;
  pwindow = NULL; 
}
```

Then I connected this handler to the x button:

```
 g_signal_connect (pwindow->gobj(), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK (on_file_quit), NULL);
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this in gtkmm. I'm satisfied with this solution, but I don't know that it is the safest/most standard.

This worked too: `pwindow->hide()`.